# Multi-line table cell

Tags: java, swing, tabular, tablecellrenderer

I have an JTable component where I display some data. One of my column is a string, which is too long for my cell. How can I make cells in that column multi-line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put into TableCell f.e. [JTextArea](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) or another JComponents that allows multiline output

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples on the Internet about how to do this. Seems like its a pretty common task developers try and accomplish with JTables. Basically what you want to do is implement your own cell editor using AbstractCellEditor/JTextArea. Heres a link to one such example with source code:

http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/multiline_in_table_cell_editing1